# GREP - patterns from a file

Tags: grep

I have a large list of MD5 hashes, one to a line in a text file.  Call it hashes.txt

I have a list of app. 40  MD5 hashes in another file that I want removed from the above list.  Call it nuisance_hashes.txt

I'm using the following grep expression:

```
"grep -r -E -f nuisance_hashes.txt hashes.txt > results.txt"
```

Instead of pulling out the nuisance hashes and leaving behind the good ones, it is giving me a list of the nuisance hashes preceded by hashes.txt:

```
hashes.txt:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
hashes.txt:0a22de7a88aa53d09581603545a223ab
hashes.txt:1045bfd216ae1ae480dd0ef626f5ff39
hashes.txt:34a754102be3d8a66dbf34785234b86d
hashes.txt:590c5944c504ed6c86b6136179b27841
```

Certainly not what I expected.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I stood back and then realized my own mistake...

```
"grep -v -E -f nuisance_hashes.txt hashes.txt > results.txt"
```

Note that I was using -r when it should have been -v